# survivor programming challenge

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on a survivor problem as shown below: Here is the [source](https://www.chegg.com/tutors/Javascript-Programming-questions/Take-a-second-to-imagine-that-you-are-in-a-room-with-100-chairs-arranged-in-a-circle-These-chairs-are-numbered-sequentially-from-One-to-One-Hundred-At-some-point-in-time-the-person-in-chair-1-will-be-told-to-leave-the-room-The-person-in-chair-2-will-be-sk--5KWRJ/)

> Complete Question Text: Take a second to imagine that you are in a
>   room with 100 chairs arranged in a circle. These chairs are numbered
>   sequentially from One to One Hundred.
>
> At some point in time, the person in chair #1 will be told to leave
>   the room. The person in chair #2 will be skipped, and the person in
>   chair #3 will be told to leave. Next to go is person in chair #6. In
>   other words, 1 person will be skipped initially, and then 2, 3, 4..
>   and so on. This pattern of skipping will keep going around the circle
>   until there is only one person remaining.. the survivor. Note that the
>   chair is removed when the person leaves the room.
>
> Write a program to figure out which chair the survivor is sitting in.

Below is the code I have:

```
public class ChairProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getSurvivors(100));
    }

    private static int getSurvivors(int numChairs) {
        if (numChairs < 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        // populate chair array list
        ArrayList<Integer> chairs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numChairs; i++) {
            chairs.add(i + 1);
        }

        // removing all but one elements
        int indexOfChair = 0;
        while (chairs.size() > 1) {
            chairs.remove(indexOfChair);
            indexOfChair++;// skip every other chair
            indexOfChair %= chairs.size();// loop to beginning if necessary
        }

        return chairs.get(0);
    }
}
```

My above method does not evict #1, then #3, then #6 as described in the requirements. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You're removing the index, but shouldn't you remove the place 'next' to that index? So start by -1 and remove 'index +1' (with index I mean Indexofchair).

Comment: kindly take a look at my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is that you introduce a second variable say `count` of type int after `indexOfChair` and initialise to 1. Now in the `while` loop  instead of using `indexOfChair++` use `indexOfChair += count;` and after that you increment the `count` by 1. As demonstrated below:

```
    int indexOfChair = 0;
    int count = 1;
    while (chairs.size() > 1) {
        chairs.remove(indexOfChair);
        indexOfChair += count;// skip the count number of chairs
        count++; //increase the number of chairs to skip by 1
        indexOfChair %= chairs.size();// loop to beginning if necessary
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the indexOfChair to be removed wrong. The position of latest removed chair is lostt in every iteration. You must keep the latest removed chair position and add incremented indexOfChair to it.

Comment: Just add a variable lastRemoved initialize it to 0, then on every iteration remove at index last removed+indexOfChair. Don't forget to do last removed=lastRemoved+indexOfChair right after the line where you remove the chair from the list.

Comment: sure. quick question. Can you tell me what will be the correct answer for this? I mean for my question, will it be 31 or 72?

Comment: No. I cannot, sorry. You will have to figure out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is similar to the Josephus problem. It may be easier to use a recursive strategy: make the first elimination, and apply the algorithm recursively to the group that is left over. Something like:

```
findSurvivor(int start, int skip, ArrayList<Integer> chairs)
  if chairs contains one element declare winner and return
  else findSurvivor((start+skip)%(chairs.size()-1), skip+1, chairs with start removed)
```

Comment: quick question. Can you tell me what will be the correct answer for this? I mean for my question, will it be 31 or 72?

Comment: I get 31. I checked the first few rounds of my program, and it seems to be right.